# How to enable LocalStorage on iOS Safari browser on private mode?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, angularjs

I am working on project SPA angular app which requires `localstorage` of browser to store values. We came to notice that iOS doesn't allow to access `localstorage` on private mode.

We fixed the issue by checking the browser compatibility for `localstorage`. If it's not allowing local storage we use `$rootScope` object of AngularJS to store values temporarily.

Only challenge of this approach is when page is refreshed data will be cleared which make sense as we are using `$rootScope` which will be destroyed upon page refresh

Here are my questions:

1. Is their any way to enable `localstorage` through `javascript`?
2. Is their any better alternative approach? Ideally we want to retain values upon page refresh. How's that possible? (Is it good to use `localstorage`)

Thanks,
Gokul

Answer (score 0):

Try using cookies instead.

`$cookies` provides a standard api of getters and setters.

Here is an example of how to use them:

```
angular.module('cookiesExample', ['ngCookies'])
.controller('ExampleController', ['$cookies', function($cookies) {
  // Retrieving a cookie
  var favoriteCookie = $cookies.get('myFavorite');
  // Setting a cookie
  $cookies.put('myFavorite', 'oatmeal');
}]);
```

And here is the full list of methods:

## Methods

```
get(key);
```

> Returns the value of given cookie key

---

```
getObject(key);
```

> Returns the deserialized value of given cookie key

---

```
getAll();
```

> Returns a key value object with all the cookies

---

```
put(key, value, [options]);
```

> Sets a value for given cookie key

---

```
putObject(key, value, [options]);
```

> Serializes and sets a value for given cookie key

---

```
remove(key, [options]);
```

> Remove given cookie

Answer (score -1):

1. No, you can't enable `localstorage` through `js` or another hacky way.
2. The best alternative I think is to use `cookies`

You can learn how to use cookies from here https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

And for `angularJS`
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies